# Bookmarklet with setInterval and ClearInterval

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bookmarklet

I am trying to create a bookmarklet in chrome that opens google.com for 5 times, but it doesn't work.

Below is the code I used

```
javascript: var x = 0; var intervalID = setInterval(function () { window.open('https://www.google.com', '_blank') if (++x === 5) { window.clearInterval(intervalID); } }, 1000);
```

After I clicked on the bookmark, there is no response.

Comment: Because the opening of the window is in a setInterval and not a result of direct user interaction the pop up blocker will kick in.

Comment: Javascript variables and code (including bookmarklets) exist in the scope of the loaded document. That's why bookmarklets don't work until a page is loaded. When you navigated to www.google.com, the browser stopped executing your code and started executing Google's.